# entity framework delete record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to delete record from table `store` but I having problem of recognizing `DeleteObject` in my code. I have reference

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Objects;
```

but it still not working. I am using `MVC 4` using `Visual Studio 2012`.

```
public void Delete()
{
    using (var db = new AppContext())
    {
        var query_D = (from b in db.Stores
                   where b.storeID == 1
                   select b).First();

        db.DeleteObject(query_D);
        db.SaveChanges();
    } 
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you're using the EF5?

Comment: `db.Stores.Remove` or `db.Stores.Delete` or anything else that is in your context version and same logic ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realized that you're using the MVC 4 with VS2012, and by default the Entity Framework version is 5.

Now the way you `delete` is from `EF4`.

Here's the proper way to `delete` using the `EF5`

```
using (var db= new AppContext(ConnectionStr))
{
    try
    {
        con.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        var o = new Store { Id = 1 };
        db.Stores.Attach(o);
        db.Stores.Remove(o);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have managed to worked with remove method as well ... thanks as well

Answer (score 8):

Just use

```
db.Entry(query_D).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
db.Stores.Remove(query_D);
db.SaveChanges();
```